# Why is issued shares less than outstanding shares

Tags: accounting

We know that issued shares = outstanding shares + treasury shares. So issued shares must be greater than treasury shares by definition. However, Starbucks' fiscal 2014 From 10-K reports

"Common stock ($0.001 par value) — authorized, 1,200.0 shares; issued and outstanding, 749.5 and 753.2 shares, respectively,"

which clearly contradicts with the concept. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Your accounting identity: " issued shares = outstanding shares + treasury shares" is correct, however you are forgetting that treasury shares are registered with a negative sign on balance sheet. So that's why issued shares are lower than outstanding shares.

Comment: I still do not understand. How can the number of shares be negative?

Comment: They are not negative. It is just an accounting convention to register them with a negative sign.

Comment: If they are not negative, shouldn't issued shares be greater than outstanding shares since it includes treasury shares?

Comment: No. Issued shares should be lower than outstanding shares. As you said: issue shares = outstanding shares + treasury shares, and as I said treasury shares < 0 (by convention).

Comment: How can treasury shares be negative? we are adding shares whose number must be positive. Would you recommend some reading on this please?

Comment: Second result on a google search:
"Treasury stock appears at cost or at par value in the shareholders equity section of the balance sheet and thus appears as a "negative" in the shareholders equity section (known as a contra equity account)."

Comment: I see that. But the problem is we are talking about the number of shares rather than the value of shares here I believe.

Comment: Even the number shows up as negative. It's a convention.

Comment: It is as a cost. However, we are talking about the number of shares rather than the accounting value of it.